# How to add 3D model object in 3Doccupancy map?

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure, occupancy-map

I have created a 3D occupancy map to model a region where I want to test some path planning algorithms for an autonomous robot. I have created a 3D map along with obstacles, but my requirement is to add 3D model (eg, human,car,tree etc anything) to my map.

The example is difficult to understand. Can somebody help me in adding some model.

Note: I have made these buildings but i want to add some sort of models (like humans, tree,car etc)
Also can we add png,or gif to our map?
[GIF of a Car](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xHZZF.gif)

[My 3D map](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MR5e9.png)

I have created a 3D map along with obstacles, but my requirement is to add 3D model (eg, human,car,tree etc anything) to my map.

Comment: It's possible I am misunderstanding your question, but couldn't you just add the 3D model you want using the same approach you used to generate the 3D map? Is there any special requirement the 3D model has to meets that made you discard this approach?

Comment: Not sure you can directly add a gif to your occupancy map, as it looks like the map is basically a ```z = f(x,y)``` function. Would you be able to share more details on how is the 3D occupancy map generated? Also, what characteristics should the added 3D model have? This kind of information would help the SO community help you.

Comment: Check the answer which i have just posted

Comment: Where is the answer you are referring to?

Comment: the answer was deleted by someone!
how can i share it to you